# How to get string from json object array?

Tags: javascript, json

I´m having problem fething any of the strings from the json provided by the google finance api. Get "undefined" when i´m debugging. . It the example below, i´m interested in the symbol(t), and the current price(l).

```
 $.getJSON("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=TSLA&callback=?",
        function(json) {
        var Stocks = json;
        var text ="";   
        text = Stocks.l + " is the current stock price for: " + Stocks.t;
        document.getElementById('Textn').innerHTML = text; 

        });
```

Comment: Read some documentation about arrays and objects. `Stocks` is an array.

Comment: You should add an example of the output.

Comment: @Sirko If he knew how to get an output he would would probably be able to solve this simplest problem.

Comment: @dfsq Ok, wrong phrasing - I meant an example of the JSON that is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stocks.l is undefined because Stocks / the response you get is an array, not a single object.

Just in case you receive an array with multiple objects, I'd use a loop - if it's an array with only one element the loop does no harm. Below uses es6 object destructuring, so be aware that it won't work in every browser at the moment:

```js
$.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=TSLA&callback=?", json => {
  for (let {l, t} of json) {
    let text = l + " is the current stock price for: " + t;
    document.getElementById('Textn').innerHTML += text;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="Textn">

</div>
```

The es5 variant would be somehting like

```js
$.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=TSLA&callback=?", function(json) {
  json.forEach(function(v) {
    var text = v.l + " is the current stock price for: " + v.t;
    document.getElementById('Textn').innerHTML += text;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Textn">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12607212",
    "t" : "TSLA",
    "e" : "NASDAQ"
    //etc
```

So to access the object properties you will need to drill into the array first to get the element you want:

```
json[0].t //gets prop "t" of elem at index 0 of array, returns "TSLA"
```